# Is there an easy way to process Streams when using mutually recursive functions?

Tags: scala

I'm translating an incoming stream of objects into a tree-like data structure, using different classes to represent different kinds of nodes in the tree. To process the streams, I have a number of mutually recursive functions that will branch depending on the next object in the stream, call each other to do part of the processing, and finally generate a single node in the tree; in other words, this is more or less a kind of recursive descent parser.

Currently I am using an Iterator to represent the object stream. The statefulness of the Iterator makes it relatively easy to work with, as each function only needs to step the Iterator forward as needed, and all other functions will automatically continue where the previous function left off, without having to explicitly keep track of the current position in the stream.

However, a combination of needing to implement various lookahead features, along with a desire to make the parser more functional and to make better use of the pattern matching features of Scala, has recently made this very statefulness somewhat difficult to deal with, as I for example need to keep track of already consumed elements in order to implement the lookahead.

As a potential replacement I've had a look at the more functional Stream class in Scala; however, using a Stream instead requires me to explicitly keep track of the current position so that other functions will read from the correctly part of the stream. I've experimented with having each function take a stream to read from as a parameter, and return the part of the stream not yet processed as part of a tuple along with the actual return value, e.g.:

```
def f2(s: Stream[X])() = {
  val a #:: s2 = s
  val (b, s3) = a match {
    case A => f2(s2)() match { case (x, s) => (Some(x), s) }
    case _ => (None, s2)
  }
  val (c, s4) = f3(s3)(1, 2, 3)
  val (d, s5) = f4(s4)()
  val e #:: s6 = s5
  (new MyClass(a, b, c, d, e), s6)
}
```

This is however incredibly cumbersome to use, what with all the extra dummy variables I need to create and keep track of just to pass the rest of the stream to the next function, as well as the constant tuple unpacking required. Is there an easier way to process streams, or alternatively, a better way to approach the problem in general?

Comment: You can create a `case class` instead of tuple and add the monadic operators to it (`map`/`flatMap`, probably also `filter`/`withFilter`/`foreach`).

Comment: @GáborBakos Sorry, it's not immediately obvious to me how those methods would behave. Do you mean that I could use them to remove the dummy variables (`s1`, `s2`, etc) in the above code while still being able to extract the values I'm looking for (`b`, `c`, etc)? Could you give an example of how I would use them?

Comment: Now it seems -for me- you might have a good use of the state monad. Do you already have Scalaz on the classpath? The following might help: [fpins/State](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala), [Memoization with state](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/memoisation-with-state-using-scala/), [Learning Scalaz/State](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html). I might be wrong, but your example looks similar to these. Others will probably answer in more detail, I have no time now for that.

Comment: @GáborBakos I don't have any prior experience with Scalaz, but I'll have a look and see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of powerful libraries out there like [play-iteratees](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.9/Iteratees) or [scalaz-stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) but i will supply you with simple solution which could lead to understanding of those.

General idea is:

1. We have some stream of elements of type `Elem`
2. Define state(s) instead mutual recursion to traverse these stream, each state is producing next state and probably some `Result` so declaration should be something like

   ```
   type State[Elem, Result] = Elem => (State[Elem,Result], Option[Result])
   ```
3. Define some function `Stream[Elem] => Stream[Result]` to process items.

So lets declare our general state container:

```
 class PStateM[Elem, Result](val receiveM: Option[Elem] => (Option[PStateM[Elem, Result]], Option[Result]))
```

first **P** is for *Process* and last **M** is for *Monadic* where monad is the `Option` ( but could be more something powerful later like `Future` in play-teratee)

We have two additional `Option`'s comparing point 2.

`Option[Elem]` means we could tell our State that stream is over passing `None` as source.

And `Option[PStateM[Elem, Result]]` in the first part of the result means we could end our computation earlier.

Let's also define the lighter version, which resembles precisely with point 2. :

```
  class PState[Elem, Result](val receive: Elem => (PStateM[Elem, Result], Option[Result])) extends PStateM[Elem, Result]({
    case Some(elem) => receive(elem) match {case (next, res) => (Some(next), res)}
    case None => (None, None)
  })
```

Nest lets define our process function like in point 3:

```
  def process[Elem, Result](state: PStateM[Elem, Result], source: Stream[Elem]): Stream[Result] = source match {
    case Stream() => state.receiveM(None)._2.toStream
    case head #:: tail => {
      val (next, res) = state.receiveM(Some(head))
      next match {
        case None => res.toStream
        case Some(nState) => res match {
          case None => process(nState, tail)
          case Some(res) => res #:: process(nState, tail)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Boy, there is a lot of `match`es, but this deepness allow our function to be tail recursive or lazy depending of situation.
Let's prove that. We'll define three key processors for handling streams:

```
  case class MapS[A, B](f: A => B) extends PState[A, B](elem => (MapS(f), Some(f(elem))))

  case class FoldS[A, B](z: B, f: (B, A) => B) extends PStateM[A, B]({
    case Some(elem) => (Some(FoldS(f(z, elem), f)), None)
    case None => (None, Some(z))
  })

  case class FilterS[A](f: A => Boolean) extends PState[A, A](elem => (FilterS(f), Some(elem) filter f))
```

if we'll use those like

```
println(process(MapS[Int, Int](_ * 2), Stream.from(1)).take(10).toList)
println(process(FilterS[Int](_ % 2 == 1), Stream.from(1)).take(10).toList)
println(process(FoldS[Int, Long](0L, _ + _.toLong), 1 to 100000 toStream))
```

We'll see first 10 evens, first 10 odds and sum of a lot of numbers without `StackOverflowError`

So lets return to you case. What about cases like tree building . Suppose we have tree structure encoded in stream of integers in following notation:

1. First we have the integer node key
2. The we getting `count` of nodes children
3. Next we getting node keys of all children - exactly `count` of them
4. After getting children we returning to step 1

So if we targeted for structure like

```
  trait Node
  case class Branch(elem: Int, children: IndexedSeq[Int]) extends Node
  case class Leaf(elem: Int) extends Node
```

We could define our processors:

```
case class NodeElem() extends PState[Int, Node](elem => (NodeChildCnt(elem), None))

case class NodeChildCnt(elem: Int) extends PState[Int, Node]({
  case 0 => (NodeElem(), Some(Leaf(elem)))
  case count => (NodeChildElem(elem, count, IndexedSeq.empty), None)
})

case class NodeChildElem(elem: Int, count: Int, children: IndexedSeq[Int]) extends PStateM[Int, Node]({
  case Some(child) =>
    if (count > 1)
      (Some(NodeChildElem(elem, count - 1, children :+ child)), None)
    else (Some(NodeElem()), Some(Branch(elem, children :+ child)))
  case None => (None, Some(Branch(elem, children)))

})
```

there three phase: `NodeElem` expecting node key, `NodeChildCnt` expecting children count and could result in `Leaf` if it's `0` and `NodeChildElem` collecting child by child, decreasing remaining count.

And this command

```
println(process(NodeElem, "1 2 2 3 2 2 4 5 3 0 4 0 5 4 6 7".split(' ').toStream.map(_.toInt)).toList)
```

prints expected structure with incomplete 5'th node:

```
List(Branch(1,Vector(2, 3)), Branch(2,Vector(4, 5)), Leaf(3), Leaf(4), Branch(5,Vector(6, 7)))
```